# Calculate width of element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I set the width of an `input` equal with `100%` - width of an `img`?

My goal is to display both of them on the same line and make the `input` to take the full width of the remaining space.

This is what I got so far

HTML:

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-1.jpg"/>
</div>
<input class="img-url" placeholder="enter img url" />
```

CSS:

```
.img-container {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img_container_width = $('.img-container').width();
  $(".img-url").width('100%' - img_container_width);
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bko38bt2/2/

Comment: Do you want to display img and input inline?

Comment: Yes, I've update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with just css using **Flexbox**

```css
.img-container {
  display: flex;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-1.jpg"/>
  <input class="img-url" placeholder="enter img url" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is that the `.img-container` has initially `display:none;` because it appears only after the input has an url...

Comment: Moved the `display: none;` to the `img` and now everything is ok. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Logic dictates that 100% width means fill the entire parent, so basically the same width as the parent element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".img-url").width(function() {
        return $(this).parent().width() - $('.img-container').width()
    });
});
```

If you want to inline the elements easily, float them or add `display: inline-block;`

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/bko38bt2/3/)

Comment: This doesn't works, I need the input to take all blank space that remains after the image because I'm also using this for mobile devices